# Why won't my integral evaluate?

Tags: integral-equations

Not sure why Mathematica won't integrate the definite or indefinite form of my function. I've tried the indefinite integral and it returns unevaluated. How can I see (and evaluate) what the actual integral looks like?

#### Code

```
L[theta_] := Sqrt[(a*Sin[theta] - F)^2 + (b*Sin[theta])^2]

Integrate[L[theta], {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
```

This returns the unevaluated integral.

Comment: Show the code you have tried, displayed in Mathematica format (not an image and not LaTeX).  Otherwise, it is impossible for anyone to offer help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You might write the integral here so that we see it. Otherwise, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Does this edit work?

Comment: Can any conditions be specified for the constants?  For instance, are they real?  If so, are they positive? etc?

Comment: `Integrate` returns unevaluated, because it cannot do the integral.  Consider using `NIntegrate`.  Alternatively, let `Integrate` evaluate the indefinite integral and evaluate it at the endpoints.

Comment: The constants are positive. a,b,F are the major, minor and focus distance in an ellipse, respectively. When I try to do the indefinite integral, I get the same result with the original equation just with the integral symbol preceding it.

Comment: What geometrical property of an ellipse are trying to compute?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer, but you may not like it.  Perform the indefinite integral and evaluate it at its endpoints:

```
s = Integrate[L[theta], theta]

ans = (s/.theta -> Pi/2) - (s/.theta -> 0)
```

The expressions are enormous.  To be specific, `LeafCount[s]` is `17739`.  `Root` appears `317` times in `s`, but in all instances are solutions of,

```
F^2 - 4 a F x + (4 a^2 + 4 b^2 + 2 F^2) x^2 - 4 a F x^3 + F^2 x^4 == 0
```

`ToRadicals` simplifies `s` a bit, so that its `LeafCount`, while still enormous, is reduced to`11644`.  Nonetheless, the result is correct.  For instance,

```
N[ans/. a -> 2 /. b -> 1 /. F -> 1/2] // Chop
(* 1.69208 *)
```

which agrees with

```
NIntegrate[L[theta] /. a -> 2 /. b -> 1 /. F -> 1/2, {theta, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Due to the complexity of the symbolic solution, evaluating it numerically seems more practical.

**Addendum**

`FullSimplify` is unable to simplify the expression, running for many hours without returning a result.  However, the expression can be broken into pieces with `Collect` and other tools, allowing the expression to be simplified piecemeal to a `LeafCount` of about `4500`, which still is very large.  This simplified expression has three instances of `EllipticPi`, which probably can be combined by appropriate identities, thereby reducing the expression by another factor of two.  Nonetheless, no simplification can be expected to produce a symbolic result that is convenient to analyze and manipulate.  Hence, it still seems best to solve this integral numerically, which is fast and accurate.

Comment: They are enormous. What does the # symbol mean in the resulting expression? How can I assign values to a,b and F after I get the enormous expression? Thank you.

Comment: Look up the documentation for Root.  I can provide more detail and perhaps a simpler solution when I have more time, probably in about four hours.

Answer (score 2):

Maple was able to solve this directly

```
restart;
r:=int(sqrt((a*sin(theta) - F)^2 + (b*sin(theta))^2), theta=0..Pi/2) assuming positive;
r:=simplify(r);
```

But the result is large. You can compare this with the Mathematica result given above.

```
(4*((I*b+a)/((I*b+a)*F-a^2-b^2))^(1/2)*((I*b-a)*F+a^2+b^2)*a*
 (-(I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)/(I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2))^(1/2)*F*((I*b-a)/
 ((I*b-a)*F+a^2+b^2))^(1/2)*EllipticPi((-(I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)/
 (I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2))^(1/2), ((I*b-a)*F+a^2+b^2)/((I*b-a)*F-a^2-b^2), 
 ((I*F*b+F*a+a^2+b^2)*(I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2)/((I*F*b+F*a-a^2-b^2)*
 (I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)))^(1/2))+((I*b-a)*F-a^2-b^2)*((I*b+a)/
 ((I*b+a)*F-a^2-b^2))^(1/2)*
(-(I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)/(I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2))^(1/2)*(F^2-2*F*a+a^2+b^2)*
((I*b-a)/((I*b-a)*F+a^2+b^2))^(1/2)*EllipticE((-(I*b+a+F)/(-I*b+F-a))^(1/2),
((I*F*b+F*a+a^2+b^2)*(I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2)/((I*F*b+F*a-a^2-b^2)*
(I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)))^(1/2))-2*(((I*b+a)/((I*b+a)*F-a^2-b^2))^(1/2)*
(-(I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)/(I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2))^(1/2)*((I*b-a)*F^2+(I*b+a)*
(a^2+b^2))*((I*b-a)/((I*b-a)*F+a^2+b^2))^(1/2)*EllipticF((-(I*b+a+F)/
(-I*b+F-a))^(1/2), ((I*F*b+F*a+a^2+b^2)*(I*F*b-F*a+a^2+b^2)/
((I*F*b+F*a-a^2-b^2)*(I*F*b-F*a-a^2-b^2)))^(1/2))+(-((1/2)*I)*b+(1/2)*a)*
F+(1/2)*a^2+(1/2)*b^2)*F)/((I*b-a)*F-a^2-b^2)
```

$$
{\frac {1}{ \left( ib-a \right) F-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}} \left( 4\,a\sqrt {{\frac {ib+a}{ \left( ib+a \right) F-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}}}F\sqrt {{\frac {ib-a}{ \left( ib-a \right) F+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}}\sqrt {-{\frac {iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}{iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}} \left(  \left( ib-a \right) F+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) {\it EllipticPi} \left( \sqrt {-{\frac {iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}{iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}},{\frac { \left( ib-a \right) F+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}{ \left( ib-a \right) F-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}},\sqrt {{\frac { \left( iFb+Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right)  \left( iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) }{ \left( iFb+Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right)  \left( iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right) }}} \right) +\sqrt {{\frac {ib+a}{ \left( ib+a \right) F-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}}}\sqrt {{\frac {ib-a}{ \left( ib-a \right) F+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}} \left( {F}^{2}-2\,Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) \sqrt {-{\frac {iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}{iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}} \left(  \left( ib-a \right) F-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right) {\it EllipticE} \left( \sqrt {-{\frac {ib+a+F}{-ib+F-a}}},\sqrt {{\frac { \left( iFb+Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right)  \left( iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) }{ \left( iFb+Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right)  \left( iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right) }}} \right) -2\,F \left(  \left(  \left( ib-a \right) {F}^{2}+ \left( ib+a \right)  \left( {a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right)  \right) \sqrt {{\frac {ib+a}{ \left( ib+a \right) F-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}}}\sqrt {{\frac {ib-a}{ \left( ib-a \right) F+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}}\sqrt {-{\frac {iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}{iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2}}}}{\it EllipticF} \left( \sqrt {-{\frac {ib+a+F}{-ib+F-a}}},\sqrt {{\frac { \left( iFb+Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right)  \left( iFb-Fa+{a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) }{ \left( iFb+Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right)  \left( iFb-Fa-{a}^{2}-{b}^{2} \right) }}} \right) + \left( -i/2b+a/2 \right) F+1/2\,{a}^{2}+1/2\,{b}^{2} \right)  \right) }
$$

**Update**

To answer comment:

```
    1.692081169+3.586206897*10^(-10)*I
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: To what does this expression evaluate for `a -> 2 /. b -> 1 /. F -> 1/2`?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Maple says  `1.692081169+3.586206897*10^(-10)*I`, please see screen shot added.

Comment: And this is an actual result versus a Taylor or numerical approximation?

Comment: Does the I (capital i) stand for the imaginary number?

Comment: @gummibear  yes. in Maple `I` means same as in Mathematica. `Maple uses I to represent one of the square roots of -1, with -I representing the other, for computations over the complex numbers.`